# Difference between google.script.run.myFunction and <? myFunction(); ?>

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new with GAS and don't know very well the difference between these two in a html file in Google Apps Script project.

**index.html**

```
google.script.run.myFunction();

<? myFunction(); ?>
```

Both functions run the function in the .gs file right? Is there any difference? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first one will run a serverside script that is in a `.gs` file and the second one will run a function inside of the `.html` file, but will not run something in a `.gs` in that project

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for are [scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets). Both call server-side functions, but scriplets are only run when the HTML Template is being built.

To clarify:

```
google.script.run.myFunction();
```

Calls a server-side function AFTER the sidebar/dialog has been served.

```
<? myFunction(); ?>
```

Calls a server-side function when your HTML Template is being built BEFORE being served.